# Javascript - How to listen when the user clicks on an image in Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, listener

I want to know an effective way to fire a function when the user clicks on an image on facebook newsfeed to do some stuff.

I could add a listener to each image but this is not very effective. Any other way?

Comment: Do you have jquery available?

Comment: I don't know jQuery. Pointers?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/c24w/DJ2ax/4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="newsfeed">
    <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2cos8hw.png" id="1">
    <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2cos8hw.png" id="2">
    <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2cos8hw.png" id="3">
    <div><a href="#">Something else clickable</a></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var newsfeed = document.getElementById('newsfeed');

newsfeed.onclick = function handleNewsfeedClick(e) {
    var el = e.srcElement;
    if (el.tagName === 'IMG') {
        console.log('Clicked image ' + el.id);
    }
};
```

What this does is attach a click event listener to the *newsfeed*.  When clicking a child element of the newsfeed, the event propagates up to the newsfeed and is caught by its click listener.  Then you check if the source of the click event was an image.

The output goes to your browser's console.  (I tested it briefly in Chrome.)